# How to style a yadcf datatable with bootstrap?

Tags: yadcf

I hacked together something that more or lesss looks like bootstrap, but all the css overrides just don't seem right: https://tdamsma.github.io/datatables-yadcf-bootstrap-webpack/yadcf.html
Is there a better way to get a bootstrap compatible datatable with all the yadcf functionality?

For anyone interested, I put this example together with a combo of webpack, datatables, yadcf and bootstrap. Repo available here: https://github.com/tdamsma/datatables-yadcf-bootstrap-webpack

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass config options for select2 or chosen to the yadcf init parameter `select_type_options`.

```
yadcf.init(table, [
    { 
     select_type: 'select2', 
     select_type_options: {theme: 'bootstrap'} 
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add additional classes to yadcf filters you can use the `style_class` for each filter

> - style_class
>                 Required:           false
>                 Type:               String
>                 Description:        Allows adding additional class/classes to filter - available for the following filters:
>                                     select / multi_select / text / custom_func / multi_select_custom_func